# Printing over the network to a Sharp MX-C311 from Windows RT

Tags: drivers, network-printer, windows-rt

So does anyone know of a workaround to print to a Sharp MX-C311 using Windows RT (over the network)?

I've looked on the website and it has Windows 8 stuff but no RT. It has generic Windows 8 64 and 32-bit drivers - I tried both and they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is through Google Cloud Print, though you will need a standard desktop computer or laptop connected to the network which supports both Google Cloud Print itself, as well as the drivers for the printer.

Look [here](http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2012/10/print-docpdftxt-files-from-surface-rt-with-google-cloud-print.html) for instructions on how to set up Google Cloud Print by installing Google Chrome and then signing into Cloud Print.

Now, set up your printer for google cloud print using the desktop/laptop. This is outside the scope of this answer since it is well-documented. And that should be it -- it should "just work".

Comment: it looks like cloud print works if your in a home environment but at an office there isnt away to allow multiple users as far as i can see.